# Assembly Programming x86 Pentium Bug

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm having a little problem in my program written in assembly language x86 Pentium. Already used the debugger to search for some abnormal thing in the run of the program. What is happening is that when i try to run it in  debugger it goes well but when in terminal Segmentation fault (core dumped) appears. I know i'm accessing some part of the memory that is not defined but i see no problem on my code.

here's the code:

```
#.text #same as .section .text
.globl hell
hell:
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
push %ebx #index
push %edi
push %esi
subl $8, %esp
movl 8(%ebp), %edx #str
movl 12(%ebp), %eax #hist
movl $-1, %esi
xor %ecx, %ecx #j
dec %ecx  

forclean:
inc %ecx
cmp $26, %ecx
je for1
movl $0, (%eax, %ecx, 4)
jmp forclean

for1:
inc %esi
movb (%edx,%esi,1), %al
cmpb $0, %al
je fim
cmpb $0x41, %al
jl if2
cmpb $0x5A, %al
jg if2
subb $0x41, %al
movzbl %al, %ebx #mover para o index
incl (%eax, %ebx, 4)
jmp for1

if2:
movb (%edx,%esi,1), %al
cmpb $0x61, %al
jl for1
cmpb $0x7A, %al
jg for1
subb $0x61, %al
movzbl %al, %ebx #mover para o index
incl (%eax, %ebx, 4)
jmp for1

end:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %esi
popl %edi
popl %ebx
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: You need to trace through the program instruction by instruction, not merely let it "r"un in the debugger. Then you get an idea on which instruction it goes wrong, and a second attempt will allow you to inspect registers for the variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the address of `hist` in `eax`, but then you do all the calculations for the character index inside `al`. Since it is part of `eax` you change the address and that's why you get segmentation fault.
Clear the `ebx` register at the beginning and use `bl` for the calculations instead.

Also your function's prolog and epilogue are wrong. They should be:

```
push %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $8, %esp    #space for local variables
push %ebx
push %edi
push %esi
```

and

```
popl %esi
popl %edi
popl %ebx
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
```